# Why am I able to assign an integer to a string in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have worked with C#.NET and this is the first time have to write VB.NET code.
So I wrote this, it compiled successfully.

```
Sub Main()

    Dim x As String
    x = 23

End Sub
```

Shouldn't I get a compile error?

Comment: Turn on `Option Strict` and it wont compile. Add `Option Strict On` at the top of the file to affect that file/class/module; or **Project Properties -> Compile** tab for the entire project; and **Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults** to make it the default for *new* projects

Comment: yep this fixed it, thanks.

Comment: implicit conversion: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kca3w8x6.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Option Strict`:
Restricts implicit data type conversions to only widening conversions, disallows late binding, and disallows implicit typing that results in an Object type.

It can be set at the project level:
[image]

Or at the file level by putting a line at the beginning like:

```
Option Strict On
```

or

```
Option Strict Off
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you allow [Implicit Conversions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kca3w8x6.aspx) probably in [Compiler Configuration Options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs91s003.aspx) by setting [Option Strict](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) to off.
You can change it in: Properties of Project > Compile tab > Option Strict.
Alternatively add `Option Strict`, at the top of the source code file, to require explicit declaration of variables.
PS
corrected, thanks @BlueMonkMN for your notice.

Comment: Note that `Option Explicit` is different than `Option Strict` and does not control implicit conversions.